# Сделать белую тень вокруг текста c градиентом

Tags: html, css, css3

Вот макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот html

```css
h2 {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-size: 104px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
  background: #503012;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #503012 0%, #A77027 30%, #F7A93B 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to top, #503012 0%, #A77027 30%, #F7A93B 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #503012 0%, #A77027 30%, #F7A93B 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h2>РАСПРОДАЖА</h2>
```

Таким способом получается белый текст, а нужно чтобы градиент остался и была белая тень вокруг как на макете. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал вот так

```css
.double_text h2 {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-size: 104px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 700;
}
    
.double_text h2.dark_title {
  background: #D7DCE0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #D7DCE0 16%, #F5F5F5 25%, #7f8081 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #D7DCE0 16%, #F5F5F5 25%, #7f8081 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #D7DCE0 16%, #F5F5F5 25%, #7f8081 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  text-shadow: 0 7px 10px rgba(0, 0, 2, .11);
}
    
.double_text h2.front_title {
  background: #503012;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #503012 0%, #A77027 30%, #F7A93B 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to top, #503012 0%, #A77027 30%, #F7A93B 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #503012 0%, #A77027 30%, #F7A93B 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
    
.double_text h2.back_title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 0;
  color: #f0f0f4;
  z-index: 2;
 }
```

```html
<div class="double_text">
  <h2 class="dark_title">РАСПРОДАЖА</h2>
  <h2 class="back_title">РАСПРОДАЖА</h2>
  <h2 class="front_title">РАСПРОДАЖА</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Работает так, но учтите, что позиционирование тени абсолютное, поэтому, возможно, придется двигать псевдоэлемент `::before`

```css
h2 {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-size: 104px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #503012;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #503012 0%, #A77027 30%, #F7A93B 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to top, #503012 0%, #A77027 30%, #F7A93B 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #503012 0%, #A77027 30%, #F7A93B 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
}
h2:before {
  background: none;
  content: attr(data-text);
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px white;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<h2 data-text="РАСПРОДАЖА">РАСПРОДАЖА</h2>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT благодарю, у меня технический долг перед SO, хотя помогать чьему-то бизнесу без обратной связи неприятно до жути